# Array to List in C (iteratively)

Tags: c, linked-list, iteration

Using the typedefinitions:

```
typedef struct Node *List;

typedef struct Node {
    int item;
    List next;
} Node;
```

The recursive solution I found:

```
List arrayToList(int arr[],int n,int idx) {
    if (n==idx) return NULL;
    List list=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    list->next=arrayToList(arr,n,idx+1);
    list->item=arr[idx];
    return list;
}
```

UPDATE: The following is almost correct, but I don't know why a zero is printed in the end.

```
List newNode() {
    List li=malloc(sizeof(Node));
    return li;
}

List arrayToList(int arr[],int n) {
    List li=newNode();
    List li1=li; /*save the beginning of the list*/
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        li->item=arr[i];
        li->next=newNode();
        li=li->next;
    }
    li=NULL;
    return li1;
}


void printList(List li) {
    while (li!=NULL) {
        li=li->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int arr[]={4,1,2,3,4,7,4,5,6,8};
    List li=arrayToList(arr,10);
    printList(li);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I get is: 4 1 2 3 4 7 4 5 6 8 0 .

UPDATE 2: Changing the function printList into this one gives me correct output:

```
void printList(List li) {
    while (li->next!=NULL) {
        printf("%d ",li->item);
        li=li->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

But I'm left wondering why should I have `li->next!=NULL` as guard?

Comment: "I wonder". Share your thoughts.

Comment: You should have `li->next != NULL` because the last element in your list will point to null.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your first element:

```
Node *head = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
head->data = arr[0];
```

You will need a pointer to keep track of your current position:

```
Node *curr = head;
```

Create a for loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i < len; i++)
{

}
```

Then for each element, add a new node and move your pointer forward.

```
curr->next = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
curr = curr->next;
curr->data = arr[i];
```

Don't forget to set the last element of your list to point to null! (This can happen outside the for loop.)

```
n->next = NULL;
```

Comment: It seems to add an extra node to the list.  Look at the update.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
typedef struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *next;
} Node;
```

Note that you want `next` to point to the next node, not list.

```
Node* arrayToList(int arr[],int n,int idx) {
  if (n==idx) return NULL;

  Node* headOfList = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  Node* tail = headOfList;

  int i = n;
  for(; i < idx; i++) {
    // Create node
    Node* node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->data = arr[i];
    node->next = NULL;

    // Link Node to current list
    tail->next = node;
    tail = node;
  }

  return headOfList;
}
```

This is just a rough draft (I've not tried it out with a compiler), but the idea is there.